# How to install Rmpfr on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: r, linux, mpfr

After `install.packages("Rmpfr")` I'm getting this error

```
configure: error: Header file mpfr.h not found; maybe use
--with-mpfr-include=INCLUDE_PATH
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘Rmpfr’
```

I typed the suggestion `--with-mpfr-include=INCLUDE_PATH` into the terminal w/o success.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look here: https://github.com/cran/Rmpfr

You first have to install the dependend libraries.

```
sudo apt-get install libmpfr-dev
sudo su - -c "R -e \"install.packages('Rmpfr', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')\""
```

It is also a better solution to install the R-Packages from the console, not inside R, since every user on the machine will have access to the package then. Otherwise it will just be in your personal library.